# How to find records that do not have a difference of two years in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table Invoices. An invoice can belong to another invoice.

```
table invoices
column id
column invoice_id (parent)
column creation_date
```

The problem is how to find invoices that do not have a 2 years delta between each one, with the `creation_date` column.

Example:

```
Good chain (delta of 2 years)
invoice_3 (creation_date 01/02/2022, parent: invoice_2)
invoice_2 (creation_date 01/02/2020, parent: invoice_1)
invoice_1 (creation_date 01/02/2018)

Bad chain
invoice_3 (creation_date 01/02/2022, parent: invoice_2)
invoice_2 (creation_date 01/06/2020, parent: invoice_1) <-- no 2 years
invoice_1 (creation_date 01/02/2018)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking at the month and the day being precise -- and presumably ignoring leap years in the process.  If so, you I wouldn't suggest using `month` or `year` interval values, because they can get funky.

Instead, just look at the previous value and check that the year, month, and day are what you want.  So, to get the first bad row:

```
select i.*
from invoices i join
     invoices ip
     on i.invoice_id = ip.id
where extract(year from ip.creation_date) <> extract(year from i.date) - 2 or
      to_char(ip.creation_date, 'MM/DD') <> to_char(i.creation_date, 'MM/DD');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select id as bad_chain_invoice
from invoices 

where invoice_id_parent is not null
and
(creation_date - (select creation_date from invoices where id==invoice_id_parent))
 > '730 days 00:00:00'::interval
```